# SQL Query optimization written for an Hacker Rank Challenge

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

For a hacker rank SQL challenge, I have written SQL script that is producing the required result. But I overused too many subqueries, I would like to know if the code can be optimized. Below is the link for the SQL challenge 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem .

Challenge details in brief :

*"Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude those students from the result."*

Here the code I have written for above challenge:

```
SELECt
   h.hacker_id,
   h.name,
   t.tot_ch 
from
   hackers h,
   (
      Select
         c.hacker_id,
         count(c.challenge_id) Tot_ch 
      from
         challenges c 
      Group by
         hacker_id 
   )
   T,
   (
      SELect
         tot_ch,
         count(tot_ch) DUPS 
      from
         (
            Select
               c.hacker_id,
               count(c.challenge_id) Tot_ch 
            from
               challenges c 
            Group by
               hacker_id 
         )
     group by tot_ch 
   )
   D 
Where
   h.hacker_id = t.hacker_id 
   And d.tot_ch = t.tot_ch 
   AND 
   (
      CASe
         when
            d.dups < 2 
         then
            1 
         ELSE
( 
            case when 
               t.tot_ch = 
               (
                  select
                     MAX(T1.tot_ch) 
                  from
                     (
                        Select
                           c.hacker_id,
                           count(c.challenge_id) Tot_ch 
                        from
                           challenges c 
                        Group by
                           hacker_id 
                     )
                     T1 
               )
            then
               1 
            End
) 
      end
   )
   = 1 
ORDER BY
   t.tot_ch desc, h.hacker_id;
```

Comment: You should start by learning to use modern, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Get the syntax correct before worrying about subqueries.

Comment: Learn about ctes, left join, union & except/minus (& left join idoms for except/minus). (Left join is inner join union all unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use common table expressions to turn your repeated subqueries into inline views which you can query just as you would a normal view:

```
WITH cteCount AS (SELECT c.HACKER_ID,
                         COUNT(c.CHALLENGE_ID) TOT_CH
                    FROM CHALLENGES c
                    GROUP BY HACKER_ID),
     cteDups AS (SELECT TOT_CH,
                        COUNT(TOT_CH) AS DUPS 
                   FROM cteCount
                   GROUP BY TOT_CH)
SELECT h.HACKER_ID,
       h.NAME,
       t.TOT_CH 
  FROM HACKERS h
  INNER JOIN cteCount t
    ON t.HACKER_ID = h.HACKER_ID
  INNER JOIN cteDups d
    ON d.TOT_CH = t.TOT_CH
  WHERE CASE
          WHEN d.DUPS < 2
            THEN 1
          WHEN t.TOT_CH = (SELECT MAX(TOT_CH)
                             FROM cteCount)
            THEN 1
        END = 1
  ORDER BY t.TOT_CH DESC,
           h.HACKER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of the `analytical function` as following:

```
Select hacker_id, name, cnt 
from
(Select t.*,
        count(1) over (partition by cnt) as same_cnt,
        Max(cnt) over () as max_cnt
   from
   (Select h.hacker_id, 
           h.name,
           Count(1) as cnt
      From hackers h
      Join challenges c 
        On h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
  Group by h.hacker_id, h.name) t)
     Where same_cnt = 1 
        or cnt = max_cnt
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
cte1 as (select hacker_id, count(challenge_id) as challenges_created 
         from Challenges
         group by hacker_id
         order by hacker_id
),
cte2 as (select c.hacker_id, h.name, c.challenges_created 
         from cte1 c 
         left join Hackers h
         on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
),
cte3 as (select max(challenges_created) as max_challenges 
         from cte2
),
cte4 as (select challenges_created, count(hacker_id) as  hack_count_same
         from cte2 
         where challenges_created not in(select max_challenges from cte3)
         group by challenges_created
         order by challenges_created
),
cte5 as (select hacker_id, name, challenges_created 
         from cte2
         where challenges_created not in(select challenges_created from cte4 where hack_count_same > 1)
),
cte6 as (select hacker_id, name, challenges_created 
         from cte5
         union all 
         select hacker_id, name, challenges_created 
         from cte2
         where challenges_created  in(select max_challenges from cte3)
         and hacker_id not in(select hacker_id from cte5)
)
         select * 
         from cte6
         order by challenges_created desc, hacker_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.hacker_id,a.name,count(b.hacker_id)  As challenges_created
from Hackers a, Challenges b
WHERE a.hacker_id = b.hacker_id
GROUP BY a.hacker_id,a.name
HAVING count(b.hacker_id) not in (select  distinct          count(hacker_id) from Challenges
WHERE hacker_id <> a.hacker_id
group by hacker_id
having count(hacker_id) < (select                           max(x.challenge_count)
from (select count(b.challenge_id) as challenge_count                 from Challenges b GROUP BY b.hacker_id) as x ))
ORDER BY count(b.hacker_id) desc, a.hacker_id

Comment: Your formatting is wrong & you just rolled back a fix for it. Please read the editor help re code block formats & look at the formatted version of your posts below the edit box before you publish. PS Code-only answers are poor. Explain why it answers the question. [answer] [Help]